# Computing "near isometries"

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

Given a finite dimensional inner product space V, and a collection of vectors $\mathcal{C}$ in V, are there any algorithms for finding nontrivial isometries of V which map $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{C}$ (or confirming that non exist)?  I am actually interested in this in a case where I would only need my isometry to "nearly" preserve $\mathcal{C}$.  There are various ways you could make the phrase "nearly preserve $\mathcal{C}$" precise, and I agnostic about how you formalize this.

Comment: Use the fact that isometries of $V$ are exactly those of the form $v \to gv + v_0$ for $g\in O(V)$ and $v\in V$. For the case of "nearly" preserving ${\cal C}$, you might be interested in quasi-isometries (with some fixed constant).

Comment: @anomaly  you have rephrased the question, but I am looking for algorithms (ideally ones which have been implemented on a computer, and can handle relatively large dimensional examples).